# IC capable of transmiting IR over multiple pins

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, integrated-circuit, infrared

recently I have been looking for a way to define a pin on the Arduino Uno. once I got that right I expected that I would be able to send IR signals over at least 5 pins.This would be because I had defined the other 4 pins to suit the characteristics of pin 3.

Below is an example of IR transmitting code for `pin 3`

```
 /*
 * IRremote: IRsendDemo - demonstrates sending IR codes with IRsend
 * An IR LED must be connected to Arduino PWM pin 3.
 * Version 0.1 July, 2009
 * Copyright 2009 Ken Shirriff
 * http://arcfn.com
 */


#include <IRremote.h>

IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
}

void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12);
        delay(40);
    }
    delay(5000); //5 second delay between each signal burst
}
```

These pins will be used to send the signal of an IR LED. My logic is that if I can  define pins then I can hook up multiple IR LEDs (one on each pin) and thus I can send a different signal to each LED.

[image]

Unfortunately This can't be done on and Arduino Uno alone. So I am looking for an alternative IC or microcontroller which will fit my requirements.

Is there any alternative microcontroller specifically built to do what I want to do here?

[**Here**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33556/how-to-choose-a-transmit-pin-in-the-irremote-library-for-an-arduino-uno) and [**Here**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33517/manipulating-3-ir-leds-on-arduino-uno) are links to questions I asked on the Arduino forum related to this post.

Any suggestions and pointers will make me very happy thanks.

Comment: is your solution working for one IR Tx RX pair?

Comment: @Umar Yes one pair works like a charm.

Comment: "Unfortunately This can't be done on and Arduino Uno"    What exactly do you mean here? Can you communicate with the receiver on all pins, one at a time?. say for ex,: only Pin 3 configured as output --works. in the next sketch, only pin 4 is configured as Tx, --works. in the next sketch only pin 5 is configured as Tx, --works?...

Comment: Irsend can only send on one pin.  That is a limitation of the library, not of the hardware.  You need to see if there's a different library for the Arduino.

Comment: If the codes are different, why not just change the IR code sequentially for all RX. I assume the alignment of Transmit LEDs isn't a concern...

Comment: @Umar each LED has to be sending a different code because each camera is in a separate physical location. I want to define each pin  with a camera so I'll be sending camera 1's password over IR using pin 1, and I'll send camera 2's password over IR using pin 2. Every camera has a different password so its necessary to have a separate led for each camera and a separate section in the sketch for the different passwords of each camera.

Comment: @Umar Iv'e already done this successfully connected to pin 3 which is the pre set pin in IR library. Now I need to do the same as what I have done With pin 3 but with many more pins.

Comment: I already have an idea of a driver board for the LEDs. Here I want to know if there is a dedicated IR IC which I can use for this purpose instead of the Arduino.

Comment: IR library isn't accessible?

Comment: It is here --> https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote

Comment: I don't want to change too much and create my own library I want to keep it simple.

Comment: If all the cameras have different passwords, can't you just parallel all the LEDs and send the commands to all of them, since only one will recognize that the command is for it.

Comment: @HandyHowie that would be nice but It won't work because the page directly after password log in is a camera number page and the field is writeable. so if the next password gets sent it messes up the number for the one already logged in.

Comment: Okay, I just read that you didn't  want to change the library,, but in case you change your mind..https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/boarddefs.h has the constant defined for Pin 3. You could probably get it done.

Comment: Get a analog multiplexer from TI or other vendor. It will solve your problem. Select the channel, send the code.

Comment: @Umar Ok I'm going to try it out. looks promising with all those output pins :D thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want an external driver for each LED anyway, in order to provide more current than an Arduino pin can supply on its own. There's no reason that external driver couldn't be a decoder/demultiplexer. You'd connect the Arduino's pin 3 to the enable input of that decoder, and use a few other GPIOs to drive the select inputs of the decoder. A 3:8 decoder would give you 8 independent LEDs that you can drive one at a time.